# How to get id of element in jquery dynamically

Tags: jquery

i have code like this

```
function slideelement(element1)
{
  $("#"+element1).slidein();
}
```

it is not working

Comment: "it is not working" is neither an error message or a proper description of what you expected and what happened instead. **Try again.**

Answer (score 2):

It is not `slidein()` but `slideDown()`:

```
function slideelement(element1)
{
  $("#" + element1).slideDown();
}
```

Comment: ok slideDown() but main problem is elementid

Comment: @user355293: Make sure that the id you are passing to is the one for which an element exists. Also post your html and example call to function.

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing in a DOM element, you can just wrap it with a jQuery object like so:

```
function slideelement(element1)
{
  $(element1).slideDown();
}
```

If you're passing in an ID string, then the code you have should be working and you're probably passing an incorrect string.